# Micro services multiple response from same controller

Tags: multithreading, microservices

Iam using micro services in my project I need to call Twp different URL or endpoint from my controller at same time and based on these two responses I will create a third response and send that third response back to controller now my doubt is simultaneously can we call two different URL from controller ??????in springboot application if yes what I need to use

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to implement the [Scatter-Gather](http://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/patterns/messaging/BroadcastAggregate.html) pattern. With spring framework you can achieve that using [Spring Integration](https://projects.spring.io/spring-integration/) and its [Scatter-Gather implementation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/4.3.10.RELEASE/reference/html/messaging-routing-chapter.html#scatter-gather)